# What should we do with the [flamingo] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

I found this tag - [flamingo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flamingo).

It appears to be very ambiguous. There are different frameworks called like this:

- [Flamingo.Php](https://github.com/wp-plugins/flamingo/blob/master/flamingo.php)
- [Flamingo-go](https://www.flamingo.me/)
- [Flamingo java components](https://github.com/kirill-grouchnikov/flamingo)
- [Flamingo-chat](https://github.com/src-d/flamingo)

And probably many more.

Burnination criteria list:

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? And is it unambiguous?

   I don't think so.
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

   Probably.
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

   Not really.
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

   Nope.

Comment: It's only 22 questions so retagging shouldn't be too much of an effort by someone who cares. I really do not care for most of the questions to be honest. The only thing I do have an opinion about is that if retagging is done, the Java questions should probably get a tag radiance-flamingo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I went through all the questions, and apart from the first 4, all the remaining were related to the Java Flamingo, which had to be tagged as [radiance-flamingo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radiance-flamingo).

Among the remaining 4, one of those was closed already, so I deleted the post (had no answers). The 3 others were related to the wordpress flamingo plugin, which I tagged with [wordpress-flamingo-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-flamingo-plugin).

Finally I merged, [flamingo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flamingo) with [radiance-flamingo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radiance-flamingo), and added it as a synonym.